# Unique row ID in R

Tags: r, duplicates, uniqueidentifier

I have to get ID from Unique function in R. I am trying to find out duplicate rows in a dataframe, which is fine but need to know what are the rows were removed from the dataframe.
I have used

```
> sam <- unique(AEData[,1:71])  #AEData is dataframe with 71 columns & 104955 observations.
```

Here the code gives me the unique rows but dont know how to get the index of the deleted rows or duplicate rows.
I have checked with other options like duplicate() to get. But Unique is quite fast for my dataset(large dataset).
Kindly help me to solve this!!!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `duplicated`:

```
 duplicated(AEData[,1:71])
```